# What is the screen called when you double-tap on the home button and shows all opened apps?

Tags: ios

Can somebody please tell me what it's called when you double-tap the home button on an iPhone and heaps of black icon boxes obviously stuff I've previously been looking at come up on the screen, giving me the option to close them or not?

Comment: These are the "recently used" apps.

Answer (score 1):

It's called Multitasking. Check out this link for more info.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202070

Answer (score 1):

It is called by a few names, such as Task Switcher, Multitasking View, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Multitasking is when you swipe from the right of the screen over and across. The "double-tap screen" is called the recently used apps.

Answer (score -1):

When you double tap the home button and you see all these different apps it is called multitasking